# Left Join two tables - dont include the joins where second table has more than 1 row for value from first table; rejects

Tags: postgresql

As title said, I want to reject rows, so I will not create duplicates.
And first step is not to join on values that have more rows in second table.

Here is an example if needed:
Table a:

```
aa |bb  |
---|----|
1  |111 |
2  |222 |
```

Table h:

```
hh |kk  |
---|----|
1  |111 |
2  |111 |
3  |222 |
```

Using Normal Left join:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN h
ON a.bb = h.kk
;
```

I get:

```
aa |bb  |hh |kk  |
---|----|---|----|
1  |111 |1  |111 |
1  |111 |2  |111 |
2  |222 |3  |222 |
```

I want to get rid of first two rows, where aa = 1.

...

And second step would be for another query, probably with some case, where is table a I will filter out only those rows which have in table b more than 2 rows.
Therefore I want to create table c, where i will have:

```
aa |bb  |
---|----|
1  |111 |
```

Can someone help me please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get only the `1:1` joins

```
SELECT a.aa,h.hh,h.kk FROM a
LEFT JOIN h ON a.bb = h.kk
GROUP BY bb HAVING COUNT(kk)=1
```

To get only the `1:n` joins

```
SELECT a.aa,h.hh,h.kk FROM a
LEFT JOIN h ON a.bb = h.kk
GROUP BY bb HAVING COUNT(kk)>1
```

Comment: `select * from ... group by column` will not work in most cases.